# Proving properties of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group, $H \subseteq G, H \neq \emptyset$. Let furthermore $X_{G,H}$ be defined as a construct with the following properties:
>
> - $X_{G,H}$ is a subgroup of $G$
> - $X_{G,H} \supseteq H$
> - for each subgroup I of G with $H \subseteq I$: $X_{G,H} \subseteq I$
>
> Show that
>
> 1. $X_{G,H}$ is distinct and is always defined
> 2. If the elements of $H$ are pairwise commutative, then $X_{G,H}$ is an Abelian group
> 3. Each element in $X_{G,H}$ is either the neutral element, or in the form $h_1^{a_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot h_k^{a_k}$ with $h_i \in H, a_i \in \{+1,-1\}, k \in \mathbb{N}$

1)

I'm having problems to handle the third property. How can $H \subseteq X_{G,H} \subseteq I$ be combined with $H \subseteq I$? Isn't this a contradiction?
How should one show that $X_{G,H}$ is distinct?

2)

This may depend on what elements of $G$ should be added to $X_{G,H}$, that are not already a part of $H$.

If $H = \{a,b\}, a \cdot b = b \cdot a = c$, but $a \cdot c \neq c \cdot a$, how can $X_{G,H}$ then be an Abelian group?

3)

This implies that all items of $X_{G,H}$ are either the neutral element or the result of the mapping of G with items or their inverse counterparts of $H$, but how do I show this? Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Regarding 1: Just like $x<y<z$ is consistent with $x<z$, $H\subseteq X_{G,H} \subseteq I$ is consistent with $H \subseteq I$.  That is, the "is a subset of" operation is transitive.

Comment: What does "being distinct" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{I}$ be the set of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$, and let $J=\bigcap\mathscr{I}$.

- Show that $J$ is a subgroup of $G$ and hence that $J\in\mathscr{I}$.
- Conclude that $X_{G,H}=J$; this takes care of $(1)$.
- Show that the set of objects defined in $(3)$ is in $\mathscr{I}$ and conclude that it must equal $J$.
- Use $(3)$ to prove $(2)$.